# Adding a Reviewer to a GitHub Pull Request

Tags: github, workflow, pull-request

In bitbucket, I can add reviewers to a pull request, indicating that I'd like them to review the request. How can I do the same on GitHub?

The only thing I see is "`Assignee`", which is only for one person. Do I have to ping them in the pull request message and/or a PR comment?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since Dec. 2016, there is a more integrated way to notify the people you want for reviewing your PR.
See "[Introducing review requests](https://github.com/blog/2291-introducing-review-requests)"

> You can now [request a review explicitly](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-reviews/) from collaborators, making it easier to specify who you'd like to review your pull request.
>
> You can also see a list of people who you are awaiting review from in the pull request page sidebar, as well as the status of reviews from those who have already left them.

[image: gif of requesting review from sidebar]

As noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262295/adding-a-reviewer-to-a-github-pull-request/41028889?noredirect=1#comment91586105_41028889) by [Alexander Amelkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286717/alexander-amelkin):

> **This feature is only for the owner of the repository**, *not* for the author of the pull request.
> The pull request author still can't request anyone to review his request.
> The only way is to mention the person in a comment.

---

[Mr. Duhart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4281529/mr-duhart) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262295/adding-a-reviewer-to-a-github-pull-request/41028889?noredirect=1#comment135825364_41028889)

> To be more precise, the option to add a reviewer is disabled for the read permission (which the author of a PR from a fork would be): cf. [Repository roles for an organization / Further reading](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-user-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/managing-repository-roles/repository-roles-for-an-organization#further-reading).

Comment: and how would this differ from the `Assignee` on a PR?

Comment: @nullpointer you assign to *one* person (https://help.github.com/articles/assigning-issues-and-pull-requests-to-other-github-users/). You request review from multiple people.

Comment: shall I assume here then that `Assignee` is by default a `Reviewer` of the PR?

Comment: @nullpointer I assume so (I haven't tested it yet). Note: you actually can assign multiple people to an issue: https://github.com/blog/2178-multiple-assignees-on-issues-and-pull-requests

Comment: Indeed. I knew that and that's why the initial query. Since that seems to differ not much now under Reviewer except for the number maybe and the task assigned. (which might leave Assignee redundant to what I can think of)

Comment: @nullpointer https://guides.github.com/features/issues/ mentions: "Each issue can have an assignee — one person that’s **responsible for moving the issue forward**". So I suppose an assignee has more rights (like close an issue) than a mere reviewer would.

Comment: True for an `Issue`  but I doubt how it might facilitate a Pull Request. Could you please guide me to where github admins can discuss on an issue or I can put this point of view further? Also an Issue is not suppose to have a `Reviewer`.

Comment: @nullpointer I agree. For issue specifically, I don't know. For pull request, I assume an assigneed can reject a PR, while a reviewer can only comment.

Comment: I don't see a gear icon in the place this GIF shows.

Comment: @ConradMeyer Probably a  right issue, like when you are not the owner of the GitHub repo.

Comment: As mentioned above, this feature is only for the owner of the repository, not for the author of the pull request. The pull request author still can't request anyone to review his request. The only way is to mention the person in a comment.

I think this should be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @AlexanderAmelkin Sure. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: To be more precise, the option to add a reviewer is disabled for the read permission (which the author of a PR from a fork would be): https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-user-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/managing-repository-roles/repository-roles-for-an-organization#further-reading

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Github you only can assign a PR to one person. And if you want to notify more people, mention them in the comments.

Comment: However, note that only the owner of the project to merge to can edit the assignee. The owner of the PR / fork can not. So the only choice in that case really is to @-mention reviewers in the comments.

Comment: From today it's outdated info (see answer on top)

Answer (score 1):

On Pull Request you can assign a team as a reviewer and the appropriate notifications go out. However, as soon as a review is posted, the team is removed from the “requested reviewers” field and replaced with the user that submitted a review.